# NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ASC_ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables `CREDENTIAL_USER`, `CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION` and `ASC_DETAILS` - whose looks like :

`CREDENTIAL_USER { ASC_ID, name, ITEM}`, `CREDENTIAL_USER { MONTH, YEAR, ASC_ID}` and  `ASC_DETAILS {ASCID, NAME, ROLE}.`

I executed a simple native SQL join to select only CREDENTIAL_USER.ASC_ID and ASC_DETAAILS.ASCID as :

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT ad.ASCID,ad.NAME,ad.CRED_EMPLOYEE_FNAME,ad.CRED_EMPLOYEE_LNAME,ad.CRED_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,ad.CRED_EMPLOYEE_REMINDER,"+
                              " cu.*, ce.*, cl.* FROM ASC_DETAILS ad,CREDENTIAL_USER cu, CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION ce, CREDENTIAL_LICENSE cl WHERE"+ 
                              " cu.IS_CRD_EMPLOYEE = true AND cl.IS_EMPLOYEE = true AND  ce.LICENSE_ID = cl.LICENSE_ID  AND cu.ASC_ID=ad.ASCID"+ 
                              " AND ce.LICENSE_EXP_YR >= "+year+" AND (ce.IS_LICENSE_YES=1 OR ce.IS_LICENSE_YES=3) AND cu.ASC_ID=ce.ASC_ID AND"+
                              " cu.ID=ce.EMPLOYEE_ID");
             List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
```

Its running fine on local, But getting `org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ASC_ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query`

exception on `JBoss` server

**Stack-trace :**

```
23:30:00,300 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ASC_ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
23:30:00,301 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)
23:30:00,302 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
23:30:00,303 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261)
23:30:00,303 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
23:30:00,304 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
23:30:00,304 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
23:30:00,305 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
23:30:00,305 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
23:30:00,306 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getResultList(Unknown Source)
 23:30:00,307 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at com.asc.dao.UserDAO.getPendingNotificationCredEmployee(UserDAO.java:991)
23:30:00,307 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
23:30:00,308 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
23:30:00,308 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
23:30:00,309 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
23:30:00,309 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
23:30:00,310 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
23:30:00,311 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getPendingNotificationCredEmployee(Unknown Source)
23:30:00,311 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at com.asc.service.UserService.getPendingNotificationCredEmployee(UserService.java:2661)
23:30:00,312 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at com.asc.service.UserService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$de8fbe27.invoke(<generated>)
23:30:00,312 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
23:30:00,313 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
23:30:00,314 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at com.asc.service.UserService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d2e7fa8d.getPendingNotificationCredEmployee(<generated>)
23:30:00,314 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at com.asc.service.ExpirationNotificationService.sendAlertToAdmin(ExpirationNotificationService.java:47)
23:30:00,315 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
23:30:00,316 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
23:30:00,316 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
23:30:00,317 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
23:30:00,317 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
23:30:00,318 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
23:30:00,318 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
23:30:00,319 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
23:30:00,320 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
23:30:00,320 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
23:30:00,321 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
23:30:00,321 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
23:30:00,322 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
23:30:00,323 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
23:30:00,323 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
23:30:00,324 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
23:30:00,325 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1) Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ASC_ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
23:30:00,326 ERROR [stderr] (pool-10-thread-1)  at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:594)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

CREDENTIAL_USER { ASC_ID, name, ITEM}, CREDENTIAL_USER { MONTH, YEAR, ASC_ID} 
both contain ASC_ID so ASC_ID becomes ambiguous in select query.
Select your data column wise and give separate alias for each column

Comment: Just to clarify: "SELECT ad.ASCID AS AD_ASCID, cu.ASCID AS CU_ASCID ..." should work.

Answer (score 4):

When using coalesce for the first time, I also run into this problem. I have solved it by writing:

```
...
coalesce(column_name, 'default_value') as key_word,
...
```

in my query.

Adding just coalesce(column_name, 'default_value'), creates several values with alias `coalesce` and this error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

If you write a query in JpaRepository, then you need to move the query and the method to the repository, which returns this object in your generic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).