# Java, Spring Boot, Hibernate, MySQL error: Encountered a duplicate sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of native-sql query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working with Spring Boot, Java, Hibernate, and MySQL to create a messaging application. My SQL statement works perfectly within MySQL Workbench, but it does not work within my application. When making a SQL call, I am receiving the error: [White Label Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK9aY.jpg)

Here are the two classes and their relationships within MySQL workbench (Constructors, Getters, & Setters are removed for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Username is required.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "Username must be between 8 and 25 characters long.")
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is required.")
    @Email(message = "Please enter a valid email.")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Password is required.")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 128, message = "Password must be between 8 and 128 characters.")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Confirm password is required.")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 128, message = "Password must be between 8 and 128 characters.")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Size(min = 0, max = 225, message = "Bio must less than 255 characters.")
    private String bio = "";

    @Lob
    private Blob avi;

    @Lob
    private Blob header;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List < PublicMessage > publicMessages;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List < PrivateMessage > privateMessages;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List < Friend > friends;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List < Reply > replies;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdAt;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date updatedAt;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "privateMessages")
public class PrivateMessage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 255, message = "Body must be between 1 and 255 characters.")
    private String body;

    private Long recipientId;
    private String recipientUserName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_privateMessages")
    private User user;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdAt;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date updatedAt;

}
```

SQL statement from the PrivateMessageRepository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM MessagingApp.private_messages  LEFT JOIN MessagingApp.user_private_messages ON MessagingApp.private_messages.id = MessagingApp.user_private_messages.id WHERE user_id = ?1 AND recipient_id = ?2 ORDER BY MessagingApp.private_messages.created_at DESC;", nativeQuery = true)
public List<PrivateMessage> retrieveAllBetweenTwoUsers(Long senderId, Long receiverId);
```

[MySQL Workbench ERR Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkbKy.jpg)

I am familiar that with Hibernate, duplicate column names will result in this error, and that the workaround is to use an alias & "AS" clause within the SQL statement. I have tried that workaround with the private_messages.id & the user_private_messages.id, individually and together, to no avail.

I am stumped because the only 2 columns that are named "id" are the PrivateMessages.id (primary key) and the "id" column within the joining table (user_private_messages), which links the user to their private messages. Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias \[ASC\_ID\] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348177/nonuniquediscoveredsqlaliasexception-encountered-a-duplicated-sql-alias-asc-id)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not answer my question. Because one of the columns that match is the primary key of one table, I cannot set an alias for that column. If I use an "AS" clause in my SQL statement, an error is returned that the "id" column cannot be found. If I change the name of the "id" column within my model, MySQL will automatically create an "id" column for the table when the program is ran, and even if I change the name in MySQL workbench.